# React Native - fetch API error: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"]

Tags: react-native, upload, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

Newbie to React Native. I am trying to use FormData to upload image and data using the fetch API following example from [Spencer Carli](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app). My back end works fine, when I use postman the image uploads to the database storage without any problem. But when I try to upload image via the mobile device I get

```
upload error [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Tunnel"]
```

Below is my code

```js
     const createFormData = (photo, body) => {
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('file', {
            name: photo.fileName,
            type: photo.type,
            uri:
                Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace('file://', ''),
            });

        Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
          data.append(key, body[key]);
        });

        return data;
      };

    const uploadPhotoHandler = async (photo) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        fetch('http://ba9737b7.ngrok.io/post', {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
            method: 'POST',
            body: createFormData(photo, {
                title: 'Golden twisted knots',
                postType: 'hair',
                duration: 45}),
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log('upload succes', response);
            alert('Upload success!');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('upload error', error);
            alert('Upload failed!');
          });
    };
```

I think the problem is from this line

```js
    .then(response => response.json())
```

but I don't know why.

Comment: what are you getting in the response?

and what is the purpose of
` Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
          data.append(key, body[key]);
        });`

you have to send just the file object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are not getting a JSON response. When you are trying to parse to JSON.
You can solve it checking first the response status code, try this.

```
const uploadPhotoHandler = async (photo) => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        fetch('http://ba9737b7.ngrok.io/post', {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
            method: 'POST',
            body: createFormData(photo, {
                title: 'Golden twisted knots',
                postType: 'hair',
                duration: 45}),
          })
          .then(response => {

            //If the response status code is between 200-299, if so
            if(response.ok) return response.json();

             //if not, throw a error
             throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
          })
          .then(response => {
            console.log('upload succes', response);
            alert('Upload success!');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('upload error', error);
            alert('Upload failed!');
          });
    };
```